# Does Ubuntu work on ASRock H170M-ITX/DL motherboard?

Tags: 14.04, motherboard

Can Ubuntu be installed on ASRock H170M-ITX/DL motherboard? If so, do you know of a good guide to use?

Im looking to create a bootable usb from on a mac of the latest Ubuntu that would work with ASRock H170M-ITX/DL .

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it'll work fine. Make sure to get 16.04.1

Comment: To make the USB, just `dd` the ISO to the drive.

Comment: @AndroidDev - any article recommendations? Will this work just fine? https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: It may or may not work. You can try it, but I would just `dd` it.

Comment: And you need 16.04, otherwise the onboard graphics won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will work on your motherboard, just make sure to get 16.04.

Comment: Why do I need 16.04? Can you explain? Thank you.

Comment: You said 'latest', I think he was simply indicating that is the latest.

Comment: It is the latest ubuntu.